# Dropping tables mySql

Tags: mysql

I am having terrible trouble figuring out the order these tables should be dropped in for my script I will post the script now, If anyone could help with the order they should be dropped in it would be a great help

```
drop table Registered_Student;
drop table EducateYou_VideoRating;
drop table EducateYou_Video;
drop table EducateYou_Violation;
drop table EducateYou_Member;
drop table Violation_Type;
drop table EducateYou_Comment;
drop table EducateYou_FollowList;
drop table EducateYou_Group;
drop table EducateYou_Admin;

commit;



create table EducateYou_Violation
(
violationId     number (9),
violationStatus char(1) DEFAULT 'X',
videoId number(9),
groupId    number (9),
commentId  number(9),
CONSTRAINT pk_violationId PRIMARY KEY (violationId),
CONSTRAINT fk_x_videoId FOREIGN KEY (videoId) REFERENCES EducateYou_Video,
CONSTRAINT fk_y_groupId FOREIGN KEY (groupId) REFERENCES EducateYou_Group,
CONSTRAINT fk_z_commentId FOREIGN KEY (commentId) REFERENCES EducateYou_Comment
);

create table EducateYou_Video(
videoId         number(9),
videoRef        varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
videoTitle          varchar2(15) NOT NULL,
uploadDate DATE NOT NULL,
videoStatus     char(1) DEFAULT 'X',
videoCategory   varchar2(15) NOT NULL,
regNo           number(6) NOT NULL,
AdminId    number(9),
commentId number(9),
CONSTRAINT pk_videoId PRIMARY KEY (videoId),
CONSTRAINT fk_r_regNo FOREIGN KEY (regNo) REFERENCES EducateYou_Member,
CONSTRAINT fk_p_AdminId FOREIGN KEY (AdminId) REFERENCES EducateYou_Admin,
CONSTRAINT fk_n_commentId FOREIGN KEY (commentId) REFERENCES EducateYou_Comment
);


create table EducateYou_VideoRating(
rating number(2) NOT NULL,
regNo number(9),
videoId number(9),
CONSTRAINT pk_video_rating PRIMARY KEY (videoId, regNo),
CONSTRAINT fk_x_videoId FOREIGN KEY (videoId) REFERENCES EducateYou_Video,
CONSTRAINT fk_z_regNo FOREIGN KEY (regNo) REFERENCES EducateYou_Member
);




create table EducateYou_Admin
(
AdminId     number(9),
firstName           varchar2(15),
surname         varchar2(15),
adminActions    varchar2(40),
CONSTRAINT pk_AdminId PRIMARY KEY (AdminId)
);










create table EducateYou_Group(
groupID         number(5) NOT NULL,
groupname       varchar2(15) NOT NULL,
regNo           number(6) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_groupID PRIMARY KEY (groupID),
CONSTRAINT fk_i_regNo FOREIGN KEY (regNo) REFERENCES EducateYou_Member
);

create table EducateYou_Comment(
commentId       number(9),
commentStatus       char(1) DEFAULT 'A',
commentTime             timestamp,
counter   number(5) DEFAULT 5,
educateYouComment       varchar2(50),
regNo           number(6) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_commentId PRIMARY KEY (commentId),
CONSTRAINT fk_b_regNo FOREIGN KEY (regNo) REFERENCES EducateYou_Member
);

create table EducateYou_FollowList(
followListID number(9),
regNo        number(9),
CONSTRAINT pk_followListID PRIMARY KEY (followListID),
CONSTRAINT fk_z_regNo FOREIGN KEY (regNo) REFERENCES EducateYou_Member
);


create table Violation_Type 
(
 violation_TypeId varchar2(9),
 violationId number(9),
 CONSTRAINT pk_violation_TypeId PRIMARY KEY (violation_TypeId, violationId ),
 CONSTRAINT fk_m_violationId FOREIGN KEY (violationId) REFERENCES EducateYou_Violation
 );








 create table EducateYou_Member
(
regNo           number(6),
status          char(1) DEFAULT 'A',
collegeId       varchar2(9) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_regNo PRIMARY KEY (regNo),
CONSTRAINT fk_l_collegeId FOREIGN KEY (collegeId) REFERENCES Registered_Student
);



create table Registered_Student
(
collegeId       varchar2(9),
password        varchar2(9) NOT NULL,
firstname       varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
surname         varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
dob             date         NOT NULL,
street          varchar2(25) NOT NULL,
town            varchar2(10) NOT NULL,
county          varchar2(15) NOT NULL,
college         varchar2(30) NOT NULL,
course          varchar2(10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_collegeId PRIMARY KEY (collegeId)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Drop Table Syntax**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/drop-table.html)

Add `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` in beginning to ignore the foreign key constraints while deleting the tables and use a single `Drop` command for all tables as once with `CASCADE` Option as below:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Registered_Student,
     IF EXISTS EducateYou_VideoRating,
     IF EXISTS EducateYou_Video,
     IF EXISTSEducateYou_Violation,
     IF EXISTS EducateYou_Member,
     IF EXISTS Violation_Type,
     IF EXISTS EducateYou_Comment,
     IF EXISTS EducateYou_FollowList,
     IF EXISTS EducateYou_Group,
     IF EXISTS EducateYou_Admin
CASCADE;
```

Alternatively, **drop all the constraints first and then drop the tables.**